# Heroku remote database must be empty error after pg:reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, psql

I have an app on Heroku and I'm trying to replace the database on Heroku with the database on my local machine.

I was under the impression that

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
```

would clear the remote database and allow me to push. However, after running pg:reset, I run

```
heroku pg:push
```

and I stil get this error:

```
Usage: heroku pg:push <LOCAL_SOURCE_DATABASE> <REMOTE_TARGET_DATABASE>

 push from LOCAL_SOURCE_DATABASE to REMOTE_TARGET_DATABASE
 REMOTE_TARGET_DATABASE must be empty.
```

Couple of questions:
1. do I have to specify local db and remote db? [I am in the root directory of my application on my local machine]
2. if so, how do I find what my local database name is? I know that heroku can divine the remote database via DATABASE_URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify BOTH the local database(where the data is coming from) and the remote database(where the data is going). The part about `REMOTE_TARGET_DATABASE must be empty.` is just a reminder to make sure you clear the Heroku database before you push.

You should be able to find your database from your `database.yml` file.

You can also find the heroku database by `heroku pg:info`

**Reminder**: Heroku runs PostgreSQL so you should be using PostgreSQL locally as well.

Comment: Indeed, it needed to be told what local database, and the yml file took care of it.